# C# listbox foreach

Tags: c#, if-statement, foreach, listbox

im studying c# and i was trying out window form application (listbox specifically) heres my code i was wondering why (cheese,ham,bacon) value isnt adding up when i select multiple items in my listbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pizza = 0;
        
        
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Hawaiian")
        {
            pizza = pizza + 100;
            
        }

        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Pepparoni")
        {
            pizza = pizza + 150;
        }

        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Special")
        {
            pizza = pizza + 200;
        }



        foreach (string item in listBox1.SelectedItems)  
           

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Cheese")

        {
            pizza = pizza + 25;
        }

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Ham")

        {
           pizza = pizza + 50;
        }

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem =="Bacon")

        {
            pizza = pizza + 70;
        }

        

        textBox1.Text = pizza.ToString();

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ks1H.png)

Comment: `SelectedItem` only works properly when exactly one item is selected. For multiselect, you have to use the `SelectedItems` property.

Comment: @JohnWu technically SelectedItem works all the time but logically it can only return one item. It's consistent in which single item is returned in a multiselect scenario

Answer (score 1):

Use `{ }` curly brackets with `foreach` loop. and move use `else if` (it will fix the issue as well as the performance of your code).

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Cheese")
{
    pizza = pizza + 25;
}
else if (listBox1.SelectedItem == "Ham")
{
       pizza = pizza + 50;
}
else if (listBox1.SelectedItem =="Bacon")
{
    pizza = pizza + 70;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ to obtain the expected result:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string,int>
{
  ["Cheese"] = 25,
  ["Ham"] = 50,
  ["Bacon"] = 70
};
pizza += listBox1.SelectedItems.Select(x => values.TryGetValue(x, out int value) ? value : 0).Sum();
```

This makes your code a bit more compact and easier to extend (you just have to add a line in your dictionary initialization if you want to add an ingredient).

Comment: And given that this is likely a programming 101 course what do you think the supervisor will say if that LINQ is handed in!?

Answer (score 0):

When you are looping on the list of SelectedItems - you used a foreach but you did not use the loop variable "item" - rather you are checking in the SelectedItem all the time.

I think below would work for you:

```
foreach (string item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    if (item  == "Cheese")  
        pizza = pizza + 25;
    else if (item  == "Ham")
        pizza = pizza + 50;
    else if (item  =="Bacon")
        pizza = pizza + 70;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting two things confused: SelectedItem and SelectedItems are different properties. Vivek has pointed out a problem with your code in that the lack of circle brackets under your for loop means that the for loop only operates on the first `if` but it isn't the real problem; yes it means that the loop will run 3 times because there are 3 things in the selected items collection but when you're inside the loop you do NOT use SelectedItem to refer to the item you're currently looping on front SelectedItems. In a list box that allows multiple selections, SelectedItem always returns just the first selected item.

Instead we should really swap the things in the listbox out for something that has the text of the item and the price of it(this is object oriented programming after all!), we should loop over the selected ones of those and add up the prices

First, let's have a class to hold our toppings and the prices:

```
public class Topping {
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public int Price {get; set;}

  public override ToString() {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

We override ToString because this is what listbox calls when it finds an item of a custom type; if we didn't our listbox would just contain the word Topping over and over because by default ToString just returns the name of the class

Next we put toppings in our listbox. Rename your listbox to be called toppingsListbox - never keep the default names of listbox1 etc; it makes things very hard to work with later:

```
toppingsListbox.Items.Add(new Topping { Name = "Cheese", Price = 25 });
toppingsListbox.Items.Add(new Topping { Name = "Chilii Oil", Price = 35 });
```

Keep going with however many you want

Now we can loop over the SelectedItems turning them back into the toppings they really are and adding up their prices:

```
foreach(var x in toppingsListbox.SelectedItems){
  var topping = x as Topping;

  pizzaPrice += Topping.Price
}
```

Then set your textbox to the price you added up